# Como utilizar o alter table modificando um atributo para PK e FK?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Eu tenho uma tabela `Funcionário`, onde sua `PK` é esse `Cod_Func`.

Depois eu criei essa tabela `Vendedor`, criei os os atributos manualmente, não coloquei o `Cod_Func` da Tabela `Vendedor` como `PK`, porque esse é um atributo que já existe na Tabela `Funcionário`.

Só que eu tenho um relacionamento entre as duas tabelas onde a Tabela `Vendedor` o `Cod_Func` é `PK` e `FK`.

Quando eu tenho usar o

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[VENDEDOR]
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_COD_FUN_VENDEDOR PRIMARY KEY(COD_FUN)
```

ele me gera um erro falando que não definir essa `constraint` nessa tabela, usando o *foreign key* ele funciona de boa.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não seria ideal você ter um Cod_Vendedor nessa tabela (Vendedor) como PK ? Tambem não entendi o que você quer fazer, você quer adicionar o que na tabel vendedor? Você ja tem a FK não ?

Comment: Acredito que o que ele queira, é criar uma relação 1 para 1 entre funcionário e vendedor.

Answer (score 0):

**Primary Key** (Chave Primária) -> Garante a Unicidade

**Foreign Key** (Chave Estrangeira) -> Garante a ligação de um ou vários registros a um campo de uma tabela...

***Possível Solução:***

Crie uma FK na tabela vendedor, e em seguida crie uma trigger para impedir que dois vendedores estejam ligados ao mesmo funcionário.

> Oracle PL/SQL

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_vendedor
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON vendedor
FOR EACH ROW
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
DECLARE cod_f number;

BEGIN
 SELECT COUNT(cod_func) INTO cod_f FROM vendedor WHERE cod_func = :new.cod_func;

 IF cod_f > 0 THEN
  raise_application_error( -20001, 'O funcionário já e um vendedor!' );
 END IF;

END;
/
```

*Está trigger verifica antes de fazer Update ou Insert na tabela, se já existe um vendedor que possui uma FK ligada ao funcionário 

Se caso já existir um vendedor que está usando a FK do funcionário já cadastrado, ele aborta o Insert ou Update*

--

Sou estudante, creio que isso te ajude!

Comment: Não seria melhor criar uma relação 1 para 1, onde um vendedor é um funcionário? Nessa situação as duas tabelas estariam ligadas pela chaves primárias e não precisaria de trigger para resolver a questão de dois vendedores estarem ligados ao mesmo funcionário. Ou outra alternativa, seria também criar uma unique constraint, evitando assim também a criação da trigger.

Comment: Por que não se deve em hipótese alguma utilizar uma `FK` como `PK`? Ele pode usar uma chave composta com a chave de outra tabela.

Comment: André, agradeço. 
Mas ainda não estou nesse estágio de criar Trigger. Ficou meio complexo para meu entendimento ai.
Mas vlw pela ajuda.
Consegui aqui. Vlw vlw

Answer (score 0):

> *Então, eu tenho uma tabela Funcionário, onde sua PK é esse Cod_Func.*
>
> *Depois eu criei essa tabela Vendedor, criei os os atributos manualmente, não coloquei o Cod_Func da Tabela Vendedor como PK,*
>   *porque esse é um atributo que já existe na Tabela Funcionário.*

O que está definido na tabela Funcionário vale somente para ela; não é herdado pela tabela Vendedor, mesmo que uma das colunas da tabela Vendedor referencie outra coluna na tabela Funcionário.

---

Para definir uma coluna existente como chave primária é necessário que ela não permita a ausência de valores; isto é, a coluna deve estar declarada como NOT NULL. A demonstração é simples.

Considerando-se relacionamento 1:1 entre Funcionário e Vendedor, e que já tenham sido definidas anteriormente as seguintes declarações de tabelas:

```
-- código #1
CREATE TABLE Funcionário (
     Cód_Func int, 
     Nome_Func varchar(50),
     constraint I1_Funcionário primary key (Cód_Func)
);
```

e

```
-- código #2   
CREATE TABLE Vendedor (
     Cód_Func int,
     Num_Percentual_Comissão numeric(3,1),
     constraint FK_Vend_Func foreign key (Cód_Func) 
                             references Funcionário (Cód_Func)
);
```

ao executar código com instrução ALTER TABLE, para criar a chave primária da tabela Vendedor

```
-- código #3
ALTER TABLE Vendedor
     add constraint I1_Vendedor primary key (Cód_Func);
```

as seguintes mensagens de erro são exibidas:

```
Mensagem 8111, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 1
Não é possível definir a restrição PRIMARY KEY em coluna anulável na tabela 'Vendedor'.
Mensagem 1750, Nível 16, Estado 0, Linha 1
Não foi possível criar a restrição. Consulte os erros anteriores.
```

Ou seja, a coluna Cód_Func da tabela Vendedor deve ser antes definida como NOT NULL, o que é simples de executar:

```
-- código #4
ALTER TABLE Vendedor 
     alter column Cód_Func int not null;
```

Feito isto, pode-se executar novamente o código #3 acima que a tabela Vendedor aceitará a coluna Cód_Func como chave primária.

---

O usual, ao se declarar as colunas de uma tabela, é definir como NOT NULL todas aquelas que sejam de preenchimento obrigatório, mesmo que não seja utilizada para compor a chave primária. No código #1, a coluna Cód_Func da tabela Funcionário propositalmente não foi declarada como NOT NULL. Mas na declaração da tabela consta a restrição I1_Funcionário como *primary key*, o que implicitamente torna a coluna Cód_Func como NOT FULL.

O ideal é definir explicitamente os atributos de cada objeto durante a declaração:

```
-- código #5 v2
CREATE TABLE Funcionário (
     Cód_Func int not null, 
     Nome_Func varchar(50) not null,
     constraint I1_Funcionário primary key (Cód_Func)
);

CREATE TABLE Vendedor (
     Cód_Func int not null,
     Num_Percentual_Comissão numeric(3,1) not null,
     constraint I1_Vendedor primary key (Cód_Func),
     constraint FK_Vend_Func foreign key (Cód_Func) 
                             references Funcionário (Cód_Func)
);
```

Comment: A agora eu entendi onde estava o erro, teve a manha de explicar, fiz aqui e deu certinho!! 
Muito obrigado!!

Comment: @LuizGustavo Deu um pouco de trabalho escrever a resposta, mas valeu pelo resultado!

Answer (score 0):

Coloquei aqui a tabela funcionário para ver se fica melhor de entender oq eu estou querendo.
Eu tenho a tabela funcionário e tenho essa tabela vendedor, o funcionário tem o Cod_Func que é a PK.
E o vendedor também é um funcionário, então ele "herda" esse COD_FUNC da tabela funcionário, então faço a chave composta, na tabala vendedor eu queria que ficasse como PK e FK.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]